# Find path of Breath first search algorithm

Tags: artificial-intelligence, breadth-first-search, expert-system

I am studying for my AI examination, and I am stuck in the `Breath first search algorithm`. According to the `Breath first search algorithm`, suppose a `robot` want to navigate from `B` to `P` on the following diagram.

I am suffering on finding the traversal using `BFS and DFS`.

Consider this matter may much appreciated.

[image]

I drew the diagram

[image]

Comment: can you show some code of your dfs/bfs algorithms?

Comment: No.It does not provide any code? It says how it moves? Traversal through node. I cant understand the path how it moves using `BFS` AND `DFS`?

Comment: Can you give us your current (wrong) solution?

Comment: sure. I will insert via image. I drew only diagram.

Comment: Your starting node should be B instead of A. Nevertheless you can see a path from B to P (B->C->D->E->J->P)

Comment: The second diagram does not properly represent the maze in the first diagram. Some links are missing in the graph, for example: P-O , O-N.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what the actual question is, but here's some code I wrote to navigate a binary tree breadth-first:

```
# Print tree breadth-first
def breadthFirst(node):
    stack = [[node]]
    while len(stack[-1]) != 0:
        newLevel = []
        for node in stack[-1]:
            if node.left != None:
                newLevel.append(node.left)

            if node.right != None:
                newLevel.append(node.right)

        if len(newLevel) == 0:
            print('\n'.join('\n'.join(n.val for n in level) for level in stack))
    
        stack.append(newLevel)
```